# Can you estimate how much the heap will be increased by Java?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

This is probably a not quite correct formulated question from a newbie but I hope you can help.

I'm wondering if there is possible to estimate how the heap will be increased by Java in order to keep the `-XX:MinHeapFreeRation=40` (default value) percent of the heap free?

More concrete:
If my heap has allocated/occupies 300 MB that means that the JVM must always keep 40%*300 = 120 MB free. Let's say that I have a memory leak and the GC doesn't help in this case. So, when my free heap space is in danger to drop under 120 MB, with which amount Java will increase the heap allocated memory? 20 MB, 40 MB? I suppose it depends on the system and the current state of the system. But let's say that my app is the only one that's running.

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: If you do have a memory leak, you should fix it.  One way is with jmap and jhat, but IDE probably have better ways to do a heap dump.  A heap dump gives you in detail all the memory on the heap.  You can see which objects take a lot of space and therefore probably should not be there.

Comment: Yes, indeed, one needs to fix a memory leak. But my question was referring to something else. Even if you don't have a memory leak (I just wrote that thinking that an example would help understanding what I want), so even if you don't have a memory leak, but the heap needs to grow, how does java calculates the amount with which the heap needs to be increased?

Comment: I have no clue.  But it probably is heavily dependent on the specific JVM you are using, so there probably is no real answer.  You could for example look in the code of openjdk if you have a lot of time to waste.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the size by which the heap grows is implementation specific. But you can always limit the size upto which the heap can grow by using the XX:MaxPermSize parameter.